# My Videos are playing onluy in portrait mode>how to play them in landscape mode also?

Tags: android

I have built a Android based Live Tv and VOD App   .

My Videos are playing only in portrait mode>how to play them in landscape mode also?

Comment: Remove screenorientation property from your manifest file inside <Activity> tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Above code contain Screen Orientation ,If your code have like this remove that,do like below code

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```